# HTTP request, content-type missing

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, cors

I've created XMLHttpRequest:

```
var body = "{cos: test}";

      this.XHRhttp.open("POST", "https://10.222.1.170:8600");
      this.XHRhttp.onreadystatechange = this.readyState.bind(this);
      this.XHRhttp.setRequestHeader("accept", "*/*");
      this.XHRhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");

      this.XHRhttp.send(body);
```

When I try to send a content-type header, the server responds by saying the header doesn't exist.

But, when I remove the content-type, the server receives "text/plain;charset=UTF8".
Why is my content-type header not being sent?

Server side:

```
 var securedServer = require("https").createServer(authOption, function (req, res) {
.......
       if(req.headers["content-type"] !== "application/json")
       {
          opt.statusCode = 405;
          opt.statusMsg = "Wrong Content-Type";
          opt.body = "Only application/json Content-Type allowed";
          RespondToClient(res, opt);
          return;
       }

    .............
    }

function RespondToClient(res, opt)
{
   res.writeHead(opt.statusCode, opt.statusMsg, {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": opt.headerOrigin,
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "content-type",
      'Content-Type': opt.contentType,
      "Content-Length": opt.body.length,
      "Connection": "Close"
   });
   res.shouldKeepAlive = false;
   res.end(opt.body, "utf8");
}
```

Comment: Have you used anything to verify that the header is actually getting sent?

Comment: When I send body, as not stringified object type, server had in request "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "content-type", but "json/application" I haven't seen. No, I do not verify that, only debug server code and check request and response object.